# Attribute error when using numpy array's astype function

Tags: python, numpy, raspbian

I am trying to convert an image to float using the astype function. On one computer running Ubuntu it works on the other which runs Raspian it give an attribute error when running this.

```
im = array(Image.open('picture.jpg'), dtype=float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 622, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __float__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 622, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __float__ 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib
```

I don't get why Image.py is on the traceback and not numpy array. Because Image.open() works fine on the Raspian distro. The problem seems to be that numpy is not working well with float.

Comment: Try calling `float` on an `Image` instance, what do you get?

Comment: @SethMMorton I get same error, except that happens on my ubuntu distro. Which makes sense since an Image instance is not a array.

Comment: @SethMMorton: But that's not why NumPy does; it calls `float` on each pixel of each plane of the image.

Comment: What versions of NumPy and PIL/Pillow do you have? Especially if you're using PIL rather than Pillow. NumPy will look for the new methods, not find them, then fall back to the old methods which worked in old PIL but wouldn't work in _really_ old PIL. I think `np.array(img.getdata())` was the really old way to do it, but I can't remember; you'd have to look at the docs.

Comment: By the way, why are you doing `dtype=float`? If you're expecting it to convert 0-255 ints into 0.-1. floats, it won't do that. If you just wanted 0.-255. floats, then that's OK. But either way, have you tried just leaving off the `dtype` and seeing whether you still get an error, or get an array of ints, or get an array of `objects` with one element that's the whole `Image`, or…?

Comment: @abarnert For PIL I have 1.1.7, and for np I have 1.9.2. This is the same for both machines.

Comment: Well, you'd really be better off with Pillow 2.0+ instead of PIL 1.1.7, but I think PIL 1.1.7 should be new enough to eliminate that particulate problem, so… no point changing it in mid-investigation…

Comment: Two last stupid questions: it is the same image on both platforms, and both were built with proper libjpeg support (so if you just open the `Image` and look at its properties, they're the same), right?

Comment: @abernert So libpng/libjpeg were installed on both platforms. And the goal here is not the code presented I just removed the excess from it to present what is the bug. The purpose is to make the image a range from 0-1 but for that I divide the whole image by 255.